# Set the Bearer token for all requests in Thunder Client

Tags: thunderclient

Is there a way to set the Bearer token for all requests in Thunder Client in VS Code? Currently I have to set it for every request.

Answer (score 1):

You can set environment variable as below in ThunderClient

[image: Variables]

and use them in all api request with variables below

here **baseurl** and **token** are variables used in below api payload, once you update these variables it will reflect in all api requests where they are used

Refer this link for more details on Thunder Client environment variables : https://github.com/rangav/thunder-client-support#setenv

[image: Token variable]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already found by now. Anyway, if you create a Collection, in the collection settings you can setup the 'global' authentication for the request in the collection.

In the 'Auth' tab you select the authentication method you want, and that will result in Authentication header with the respective token included for the all the requests in the collection.